# Upgrading sprockets-rails gem breaks tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, rubygems, sprockets

After upgrading to `sprockets-rails` version 3.0 from version 2.3.3, the integration test below fails. It used to pass but now gives the error: `Expected exactly 2 elements matching "img[src*='profile.gif']", found 0..`.

The test:

```
get user_path(@user1)
puts @response.body
assert_select "img[src*='profile.gif']", count: 2
```

`puts @response.body` confirms that the image is there twice as the body includes two times: 
`src="/assets/account/profile-3454be0beae***256dab6d.gif"`. Nevertheless the test fails.

Does anyone understand this? And how should I solve it?

Comment: Try to add `config.assets.digest = false` to `config/environment/test.rb`.

Comment: Thanks, then indeed the test passes. Could you explain? Is it okay to add this to the environment configuration?

Comment: I don't know why this value was `true` by default in your configuration, digests are only used in production environments. However I use sprockets 2.3.3 yet, and this problem could be a result of 3.0 behavior, so it seems I will meet similar problem after update.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change seems to be related with `rails 4` as stated in the [Asset Pipeline documentation](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html):

> Rails 4 no longer sets default config values for Sprockets in test.rb,
>   so test.rb now requires Sprockets configuration. The old defaults in
>   the test environment are: config.assets.compile = true,
>   config.assets.compress = false, config.assets.debug = false and
>   config.assets.digest = false.

So if digests are not expected in the test environment it should be explicitly configured in the `config/environments/test.rb` file:

```
config.assets.digest = false
```